# Detect when widget changes position in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there any way to detect when a widget changes position? Such as when the keyboard pops up and the content is shifted up? I would like to detect this without relying on focus events or trying to detect the keyboard state.

Here's an example app:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyTextField()
        )
      )
    );
  }
}

class MyTextField extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField();
  }

}
```

How can you detect when `MyTextField` is moved up when it is focused?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `WidgetsBindingObserver` to detect when the metrics change, here you have a sample but you will have to use GlobalKey to check the new position of your Widget :

```
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
      GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();

      @override
      void initState() {
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
        super.initState();
      }

      @override
      void dispose() {
        WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
        super.dispose();
      }

      @override
      void didChangeMetrics() {
        final RenderBox renderBox = _key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
        final position = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
        print("position : ${position.dx},${position.dy}");
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: MyTextField(
              key: _key,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class MyTextField extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyTextField({Key key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return TextField();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, I thought this was working but I believe that the position printed in `didChangeMetrics` is actually the old position of the TextField, before it changed position. Is there a way to get the new position?

Comment: It works only if window metrics change but not the widget's position

Comment: @diegoveloper I'm getting `A value of type 'RenderObject?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'RenderBox?'.`

Comment: @TănaseHagi You can try `_key.currentContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find out if the keyboard is visible, you can use this:

```dart
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeMetrics() {
    print('Is the keyboard visible? ${window.viewInsets.bottom != 0 ? 'yes' : 'no'}');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: TextField(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Explaination: By getting the bottom position of the rectangle in which your app is drawn, you can deduce whether a system component has reduced the space of your app, hence if the keyboard is visible.

This answers only this part of your question:

> Such as when the keyboard pops up and the content is shifted up?

But at least the size of the rectangle in which your app is drawn is always the current one and not an old size. This is the problem with @diegoveloper's answer, you always get the old position of the `TextField`.